# Enable TLS in HTTP client with Post request

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tls1.2

I want to add TLS 1.2 to the below code, Tried by creating socket but no luck. Can someone help on it ? Can we add it after creating a client ?

```
  private static int executeSOAPRequest(String req, String targetURL)
        throws Exception {
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(targetURL);
    post.setRequestBody(req);
    post.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
            "text/xml; characterset=ISO-8859-1");
    post.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "\"\"");

    // prepare HTTP Client
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter("SOAPAction", "\"\"");

    // Post the request
    int respCode = client.executeMethod(post);
    System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());
    // If response is not success
    if (respCode != 200)
        throw new Exception("Executing SOAP request has failed.");
    // Convert the response into NOM XML
    int resp = 0;
    Document doc = nomDocPool.lendDocument();
    try {
        resp = doc.parseString(post.getResponseBodyAsString());
        nomDocPool.returnDocument(doc);
    } catch (XMLException e) {
        nomDocPool.returnDocument(doc);
        //logger.error("Exception while generating SAML : "
                //+ e);
        throw e;
    }
System.out.println("resp: "+resp);
    return resp;
}
```

Comment: I want to set TLS to the above code

Comment: What version of java are you using? Java 8 has much better TLS defaults than Java 7.

Comment: I use java 7 and As of now i wont be able to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` already handles TLS for you.  This is documented:

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html

> HttpClient provides full support for HTTP over Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) or IETF Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocols by leveraging the  Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE). JSSE has been integrated into the Java 2 platform as of version 1.4 and works with HttpClient out of the box.

All you have to do is make sure your `targetURL` is using `https://` instead of `http://`, then `HttpClient` handles the rest for you.

Comment: I am passing https in my targetURL. In my case i have a soap Request and endpoint (targetURL), so we fire this request to an external system, The external system is changed to TLS v 1.2 , so  i am getting error

Comment: I try to connect with Salesforce , I get the below error "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>sf:UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT</faultcode><faultstring>UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.</faultstring><detail><sf:UnexpectedErrorFault xsi:type="sf:UnexpectedErrorFault">

Answer (score 0):

Forget HttpClient. Use **javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection**.

```
String myResponse = null;
URL url = new URL(targetURL);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; characterset=ISO-8859-1");
con.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "\"\"");

con.setRequestMethod("POST");       
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);      
con.setSSLSocketFactory(My_Lovely_CertificateHelper.getSslSocketFactory());
con.connect();

OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "ISO-8859-1");
osw.write(req);
osw.flush();
osw.close();

InputStream is = null;
if (con.getResponseCode() < HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
    is = con.getInputStream();
} else {
    is = con.getErrorStream();
}
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "ISO-8859-1");

int read = -1;
char[] buff = new char[1024];
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while ((read = isr.read(buff)) != -1) {
    sb.append(buff, 0, read);
}
myResponse = sb.toString();
return myResponse;
```

---

getSslSocketFactory()

```
public static SSLSocketFactory getSslSocketFactory() throws Exception {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        String trustStorePath = getcertPath();  //"user.dir" + "\ohHappyDays.jks";
        String password = "finallyFoundLoveIn2021";
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(trustStorePath), password.toCharArray());
        kmf.init(ks, password.toCharArray());
        sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), (TrustManager[]) null, (SecureRandom) null);
        return sc.getSocketFactory();
}
```